# How can I write list type returning value in Linq with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0, ado.net-entity-data-model

How can I return `List<personel>` data type from below procedure. If I press F5 it throw me this error:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?) C:\Documents and
>   Settings\yusufk\Desktop\EFTestSolutions\WebApplicationTest1\WebApplicationTest1\Default.aspx.cs
>   101 61 WebApplicationTest1

I think that I should rearrange or recode  "select new {. . . . " ?

```
protected List<personel> GetPersonalsData2()
{
    List<personel> personeller;
    using (FirmaEntities firmactx = new FirmaEntities())
    {
       personeller = (from p in firmactx.Personals 
                      select new { p.ID, p.Name, p.SurName });
       return personeller.ToList();
    }
 }

 public class personel
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part is returning an anonymous type:

```
personeller = (from p in firmactx.Personals select new { p.ID, p.Name, p.SurName });
return personeller.ToList();
```

It needs to be:

```
personeller = (from p in firmactx.Personals 
               select new personel { Id = p.ID, 
                                     Name = p.Name, 
                                     SurName = p.SurName }).ToList();
```

Or if that collection is of type `personal` already, you can do this:

```
personeller = (from p in firmactx.Personals select p).ToList();
```

Or, just this:

```
personeller = firmactx.Personals.ToList();
```

In your posted code it's trying to return `List<yourAnonymousType>` (directly from the IQueryable, another invalid cast) instead of `List<personal>` and can't convert between the two, you need to be dealing with the same type.

Comment: Nick; thanks your post but i need Personels entites's  p.ID, p.Name, p.SurName values so i write new class personel class. So i should return value List<personeller> type....

Comment: @programmerist - In that case, use my first option, the one after "It needs to be:". Just call `return personeller;` after that, no need for a 2nd `.ToList()`.